# Request Routing - Page routes but CSS/JS don't

Tags: css, iis, iis-7, request, url-routing

I am trying to setup IIS7.5 to rewrite traffic coming in to my webserver to a website on a different server in the same area of our Network. The content I am going to be presenting back is coming from Apache.

I am at the point where I am able to enter http://example.org/online-apps and that will rewrite to http://myOtherExample/online-apps.  I am getting the default page I was hoping to see, but it is devoid of any css/js files. Upon looking at the source delivered back to the client machine, I can see that all of the css and js references on page are relating to addresses like this: http://myOtherExample/online-apps/css/site.css  . Obviously if I navigate to this address, my request will fail as myOtherExample isn't publicly available.

As a developer, my first thought would be that I was using relative addresses on these links and that is naughty for this kind of thing. I guess absolute paths might be just as painful. The website I am presenting back is 3rd party, I cant change any of their html and they assure me that this is working in other companies just fine. Must be my limited ARR knowledge then.....

My question therefore is how do I get all of these resources to load correctly? As far as I can see I need to somehow intercept those relative addresses and change them so the clients browser can load the resources and the page looks and works as beautifully as it was designed.

Can anyone offer me any assistance to make that work please? I was thinking outbound rules, but my knowledge on those isn't great.

many thanks

Comment: have a look into the url rewrite 2 for iis module - might be what you are after

Comment: I'm using an inbound rule on IIS to divert the traffic from example.org to otherExample, but the css and js are not getting re routed